# Map not displaying from Javascript using fusion table

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I have this javascript which I am working on but the map in the HTML is just not displaying. I have a similar fusion table with layer_1 which is displaying fine but when I put layer-2 instead of layer_1 and pull up a different tableid with same code. The map does not show up.

```
var tableid_2 = 431xxxx; 
var layer_2;
var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';
var zoom = 7;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(3x.7996, -11x.1668);

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    zoom : zoom,
    center : latlng,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
},
scaleControl: true,
scaleControlOptions: {
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
},
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);




layer_2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid_2);
var qry = "SELECT 'Location2', 'Name2','URL' FROM " + tableid_2;
layer_2.setMap(map);

layer_2.enableMapTips({
    select: "'Name2'",
    from: tableid_2,
    geometryColumn: 'Location2', 
    suppressMapTips: false, 
    delay: 50,
    tolerance: 5
});
addListeners();



layer_2.setQuery(qry);

var col_list = 'Name2';

if(order_list && order_list !== 'Name2') {
    query += " ORDER BY " + order_list;
}

var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + qry + queryUrlTail);




$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : queryurl,
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : dataHandlerCallback,
    error : function() {
        alert("AJAX ERROR for " + queryurl);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you obfuscating your table id?  Jason is right, your table must be public to display in the GMap API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your fusion table is public, otherwise it will not show up.